# Can't install CodenameOne plugin in Netbeans 12.0

Tags: netbeans, codenameone

I have already installed the plugin and it worked fine, but after a few changes, I had to remove it and reinstall it.
Now for some reasons Netbeans asks for the plugin `org.openide.execution.deprecated`, but I don't know how to find it nor to solve this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans and IntelliJ broke the plugin APIs in recent versions. We no longer maintain these and encourage developers to migrate to Maven using https://start.codenameone.com/ or the migration tool. This is supported on all IDEs out of the box.

Comment: I tried. I keep getting java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException even without a single line of code because `Cannot find codenameone_settings.properties`

Comment: In Netbeans 12.5. It seems to work in Intellij

Comment: Where do you get it from? Again, you don't need the plugin. A maven project must include that file and comes with that file from the initializer.

Comment: I'm trying to create a project without the plugin, so i download a "bare-bone java app" from https://start.codenameone.com/ for netbeans.
When I open the project (*****-javase) and build it, I get the error `Cannot find codenameone_settings.properties at ***/***/***/javase codenameone_settings.properties`

Comment: Did you select netbeans as an option when downloading? Notice the default is intellij/IDEA. 
You shouldn't open the java-se project. You open the root directory and work with the hierarchy.

Comment: How would we use the UI builder(The feature most attractive to me) if we cannot install the plugin??

Comment: See https://shannah.github.io/codenameone-maven-manual/#create-gui-form there's several GUI related targets.